# Synchronized data exte

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We have integrated our Salesforce and Marketing Cloud instances via the Marketing Cloud Connector.  Our Marketing Cloud instance has 4 business units.  We recently set up a synchronized data source between Salesforce and the Marketing Cloud at the parent business unit.  However, we need to access the synchronized data extension from one of the child business units.  Our understanding is that we need to write a query for this but we aren't having any luck finding any documentation regarding how to write a query.  Please point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, you can manage this through a combination of queries, date extensions, and automations to populate children business units (BUs).

1. Create as many regular Data Extensions (DEs) in the parent BU as you need to populate from the Synchronized Data Source (SDS) DEs.
2. Create your queries to push from the SDS DEs into regular DEs.
3. Setup up an automation to run your queries on a schedule.
4. Replicate steps 1 through 3 as needed in the appropriate BUs.

Depending on your data model, you may need to break things into pieces in order to manage this effectively.

One major difference in the child BUs is you will need to modify your queries to pull from the parent. Add the prefix "Ent" to your parent object(s). It's important to either name the field attributes exactly the same in both places or include naming convention logic to avoid errors. Here's a simple example that shows how to pull some data from the Contact object:

```
Select 
  c.id as "Contact ID"
, c.email as "Contact Email"
from Ent.Contact_Salesforce as c
```

In this scenario, I did not use Shared Data Extensions because each BU needed its own data that was not to be shared with any other BUs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access synchronised DEs in child BU, I recommend below steps:

1. In Shared Data Extension folder, create folder for each business unit, for example if you have two BUs:  Home Service and Business Service, the folder structure looks like:

> Shared Data Extension
>
> - Home Service
> - Business Service

2. Right click on each BU folder and only give permission to that child BU and parent BU, so user in one BU cannot access the data folder for another BU
3. In Child BU folder, create data extension with fields exactly like your Synchronized data extension (Lead_Salesforce, Contact_Salesforce etc)
4. In Parent BU's Automation Studio, create an Automation job, for the 1st step: drag a query activity to write query to copy data from Syncrhonized data extension into new data extension. for example for Lead_Salesforce

> select * from Lead_Salesforce

Then select the DE you created in Shared Data Extension-> Child BU folder, use "Overwrite" type, when it runs it will empty the target DE and fetch all records again.

Setup schedule to run every x minutes (by default, synchronised DE are refreshed every 15 minutes, so you can set your automation job to run every 30 minutes. 1 hour etc)

5. You should have data available in that DE at child BU level.